# get informations of an apk file to check version number

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add an auto-update function to check if an apk file is newer than the installed version.

I found several posts for android, but that doesn't work for xamarin :

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String apkName = "example.apk";
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + apkName;        
PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(fullPath, 0);
Toast.makeText(this, "VersionCode : " + info.versionCode + ", VersionName : " +
               info.versionName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How could I check a version name and number?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Config file in my app's shared project, which defines a number of global constants I require.

One of these constants is

```
public static Version AppVersion = new Version(2, 3, 45);
```

In our web application, to which the app connects, there is a REST method, which returns, along with other server defined configuration parameters, the current app version, which has been defined as the mimimum version to use with this web application.

These parameters are being stored in a class called "ConfigParameter"

```
public Version MinAppVersion
{
    get
    {
        return new Version(MinAppVersionString);
    }
    set
    {
        MinAppVersionString = value.ToString(3);
    }
}
public string MinAppVersionString = string.Emtpy;
```

Basically MinAppVersion just wraps the string I gathered from the server to a System.Version object.

When reading the ConfigParameters from the json response, I set minAppVersion with:

```
ConfigParameter.Instance.MinAppVersionString  = jsonData.Value<string>("minAppVersion");
```

This enables me to compare the current version with the one our web application tells me to use:

```
int versionMinResult = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigParameter.Instance.MinAppVersionString)) ? Configs.AppVersion.CompareTo(ConfigParameter.Instance.MinAppVersion) : 1;
```

The version check result can have three possible values:

- 1 -> The current app version is newer than the server requires
- 0 -> The current app version is equal with the one the server requires
- -1 -> The current app version is older than the server requires

The only downside with this approach is that you have make sure that the version in your global constants config is set to the same version you enter in your Android and iOS projects.

Instead of getting the minVersion from a REST API you should be able to read the VersionName and put it's value into ConfigParameter.Instance.MinAppVersionString.

I haven't tested it, but this should give you the versionName.
Add this class to your Android project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceServices))]
namespace YourApp.Droid.Services

public class YourApp.Droid.DeviceServices : IDeviceServices
{
    public string GetVersionName()
    {
        String apkName = "example.apk";
        String fullPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + apkName;
        PackageInfo info = MainActivity.Current.PackageManager.GetPackageArchiveInfo(fullPath, 0);
        return info.VersionName;
    }
}
```

Then in your shared project add a new Interface:

```
public interface IDeviceServices
{
    string GetVersionName();
}
```

And then where you want to have your version check, add

```
string versionName = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceServices>().GetVersionName();
```

If course you could add the GetVersioName method to a similar interface, you might already have in your project, as long as it runs in your android subproject.

Comment: thank you for this answer, you get new version's informations from a rest method if I'm not mistaking, but is there a way to get them from an .apk file located on the device ?

Comment: I haven't implemented a version check of a pre-downloaded apk, yet.

You would have to implement an interface in your shared project and then implement the version check of the apk in your android project. However I am not sure how reliable that will work. Our app had an auto update functionality which downloaded and installed the new apk automatically, however that functionality broke with android 10.

Comment: I have extended my answer. Please note, that I haven't tested the code, but in theory, it should be a valid port of the code you tried to use for Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried to get package archive info, but it returns always null, it seems it can't locate the apk file, or can't open it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information you want through this link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking), and there is a video that explains in detail how to control the version number.